# Compare outer type of typing objects

Tags: python, python-3.8

I'm developing a module for converting types that are defined using Python's `typing` library. I'd like to determine if the given type is a list as seen below:

```
def is_list(input_type):
   """Return if the given input_type is List"""
```

```
is_list(List[int]) -> True
is_list(List[str]) -> True
is_list(Dict[str, str]) -> False
```

Is using `._name` the best approach here, or is there a better way to extract the outer type that doesn't require me to use a private attribute?

```
List[int]._name
'List'
```

Comment: I guess you can just use `isinstance(input_type, list)`

Comment: you have the type() method in python which is much easier...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's [`typing.get_origin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_origin):

```
>>> typing.get_origin(typing.List[int])
<class 'list'>
>>> typing.get_origin(typing.List[int]) is list
True
```

Comment: the type() method is much easier, but i still agree with your solution, they will work fine, :)

Comment: @SARANSURYA: `type` does something entirely different. You're not going to get anything useful out of calling `type` on `typing.List[int]`. `type([1, 2, 3])` is `list`, but we have `List[int]`, not `[1, 2, 3]`.

Comment: fwiw `typing.get_origin` is python 3.8+.

Comment: Thanks @user2357112supportsMonica I forgot the String part,